# Cannot find a public type named PresentationUIStyleResources

Tags: wpf, xaml, documentviewer

I am new to WPF and XAML, but after a few hours of googling I cannot figure out what is wrong here. I have PresentationUI assembly added as a reference.

"The type reference cannot find a public type named 'PresentationUIStyleResources'. Line 14 Position 44."

The error occurs on the first line with 'PresentationUIStyleResources'.

What I'm trying to do is take the default DocumentViewer them and remove the Print button and find textbox. I then want to add a few more cbuttons and their functionality. But this error has been holding me back for a while. Anyone know why?

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System_Windows_Documents="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Documents;assembly=PresentationUI" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Height="353" Width="361" OverridesDefaultStyle="True">

<UserControl.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="DocumentViewerStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerContextMenu, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResoures}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
                    <Border Focusable="False" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentControl Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerToolBarStyleKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" TabIndex="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" IsTabStop="true" TabIndex="1" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" CanContentScroll="true" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
                                <FrameworkElement Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                                <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="top" Height="10" Visibility="Visible">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#66000000" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <ContentControl TabIndex="2" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DocumentViewer   x:Name="MyDocumentViewer" Style="{DynamicResource DocumentViewerStyle1}"/>
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Note: I have pretty much been trying to find code on MSDN for this, which is what the above is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misprint in your XAML at specified in error position. Should be `PresentationUIStyleResources` instead of `PresentationUIStyleResoures` (check names by letters).